# What makes a song a "rock" song?

Tags: rock-n-roll

Sometimes I'm not completely sure when a song is a "rock song" or when it is from another music genre or even a "something-rock" song. How do you recognize it? Is it some bass rhythm? Some chord progressions? Some guitar picking pattern? The instruments? Some scale?

I find myself very confused with this. The rock in the 50's doesn't really have much to do with what people say it's rock in this days, and I even confuse some other genres with "rock" or "rock-something".

I liked a lot the music from Nirvana for example, and for me and a lot of people that was rock, until I discovered it was grunge which is a subgenre of a subgenre, inspired by other genres and so on...

Is there a way to recognize it by paying attention to some characteristic of the melody, or is it just the feel of it?

I looked in wikipedia and there are more than two hundred subgenres of rock, a lot of them mixed with other genres and stuff, so how do you know a song is a rock song, or that a group is a rock group?

Is there a simple or at least consistent way to know this?

Comment: Anything  that can't really be placed in any another genre and is played with a small ensemble and electric instruments can be called "rock".

Comment: Back in the '60s, if you could jive to it, it was rock'n'roll. If not, it wasn't.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Rock music is defined by *rhythm*, not melody. Rock is in 4/4 time with the heavy beats being 2 and 4.

Rock and roll in the '50s has exactly this in common with all of your "sub-genres" that you consider to be "rock" today. It's that simple.

I'm constantly amazed at how many people around the world today have essentially only listened to rock music all their lives and don't realize that there are many other kinds of music today and throughout history that don't use 4/4 time with the heavy beats on 2 and 4 at all.

The majority of Western music that is in 4/4 time, throughout history, has a different beat,  where the heavy beat is 1, while 2, 3 and 4 are weak beats. (Examples are the whole of European classical music, contemporary Mexican pop music, like *banda* and *norteño*, of which there is a lot in my neighborhood, and dances like the *foxtrot* or *tango*). There is also a great deal of music in the world that uses time signatures other than 4/4, such as the waltz, in 3/4, or the minuet, in 6/8.

If it is in 4/4 time and you clap along to it on the 2 and the 4, then it's rock music, or one of other related forms with a broader history such as the blues, jazz, country, R&B (rhythm and blues), or gospel. All of these forms come down to us from the rhythm of African-Americans, whose ancestors exported this rhythm from its birthplace in Africa when they were forcibly relocated to the New World.

Genres and sub-genres of "rock" notwithstanding, they all have this in common: the *predominant* rhythm is 4/4 with the heavy beats on 2 and 4. That is why all these sub-genres are called "rock".

Listen to other kinds of music that have nothing to do with rock, and you'll understand that the world of music is vast, but that rock is a very narrow genre with a very short history that just happens to be really popular in *your particular culture* in the present.

Comment: Then of course there is [progressive rock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_rock) where 4/4 might not be predominant. ;-P No rule without exception...

Comment: Indeed. But even prog rock and progressive metal use 4/4 with a rock beat often enough that it's clearly a defining characteristic. I am a huge lifelong fan of progressive rock!

Comment: Great answer!! I was afraid the question was deemed as subjective or something but I knew there was some theory behind this

Comment: Nice answer, although it'd be nice to clarify the difference between rock and jazz, blues, country, etc. I would say that jazz is usually swung, while rock is straight. Jazz also tends to use more piano and brass. Country uses more finger picking than rock (and maybe syncopation?), and banjos :D. I'm not very familiar with R&B and Gospel, but I'd say much slower beats, more focus on voice, vocal harmonies, religiosity, and slower melodies. Blues is more difficult, since it's a lot closer to Rock... um, slide guitar? Can be more swung and syncopated too.

Comment: naught101, that is really an old characterization of Country. I mean, yeah, in some corners there's a lot of that Chet Atkins stuff, but since the 90s Country music has sounded a lot like Rock music.

Comment: @VarLogRant: sure. I'm not a big country fan, so I'm not surprised that I'm way off. I was just supplying some examples, in order to prompt someone else into improving the answer. If I was more certain, I would have added it myself :)

Comment: There is also a lot of music in 4/4 with accents on 2 and 4 that is not considered rock music. I think there are also other factors defining rock music, e.g. chord progressions and the choice of instruments.

Comment: I agree with tomp. While 4/4 time with accents on 2 and 4 is a characteristic of rock music, it also is characteristic of jazz, classical and other genres. In addition to chords (power chords?), instruments (electric guitar, electric bass, drums), you also might consider song structure (32-bar, AABA) as a defining element.

Comment: BTW, the info for the rock-and-roll tag contains a description. See http://music.stackexchange.com/tags/rock-n-roll/info.

Comment: "Rock is in 4/4 time" - tell that to Neal Peart (Rush) ! ;-) just pointoung out exceptions to a rule

Comment: Grateful Dead and many other "rock" bands use other time signatures besides 4/4.

Comment: By this answer's definition this song is not a rock song, but it obvs is.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xTgKRCXybSM&list=PLD0F66438C48D23C1&index=4&t=0s

Answer (score 10):

This is really one of the most subjective areas in music, and one that individuals who follow a sub-genre get most militant about.

In my opinion, the only **real** way to do this is by comparison with other songs/bands in a particular genre. There are exceptions, for example Industrial - which has well defined descriptions based around the use of industrial noises sampled as percussion - but even this has a great deal of debate.

Even sites like [rock.about.com](http://rock.about.com/od/rockmusic101/a/subgenres.htm) have limited information on subgenres, and they use listings of bands in that subgenre as an indicator.

This image from [Whitehotmagazine.com](http://www.whitehotmagazine.com/UserFiles/image/Keith_Brown/rock-genre-v1.jpg) shows how complex the subgenre fields are:
[image]

**tl;dr** - don't worry about it. If you really need to know what genre a particular song is, find out who played it and try looking on their website, or asking a fan.

(For those who really want to know - [Metaltech](http://www.metaltech.me) is Industrimental - bringing together classic rock, techno, industrial, funk and metal... :-)

Comment: Great diagram. Is there a higher res version somewhere? Some of it is pretty hard to read.

Comment: Your link to the whitehotmagazine image just loads their logo for me, I'm guessing they cache it for those who visited the page while those of us who see the hotlink are out of luck :P

Comment: This one is a bit better (v2 of same diagram) - found by searching google images for  "Ward Shelly Rock Genres": http://www.wardshelley.com/paintings/pages/fullpics/rockgenres-v2%20copy.jpg   Original images seems to be  from this article : http://whitehotmagazine.com/articles/next-invitational-exhibition-emerging-art/1263

Answer (score 8):

Defining "rock" through a checklist of features (4/4 rhythm, guitars, beats on 2 and 4, guitarists who trash bathrooms) is a fools' errand. For every possible item on that list, there are counterexamples, and usually you can even find counterexamples within the canon of rock classics.

Personally, I find it is better to think of Rock as a loose tradition, rather than a genre. Rock has existed for almost 3/4 of a century now, of course it's changed in that time. You'd run into the same problem of vague genre definitions if you tried to define how "classical music" sounds. Every step on the way from Blues Rock and Rock&Roll to the huge landscape of rock and metal genres we have today is small enough to appreciate how we got from here to there, but overall, it's like comparing an expertly crafted hole in the ground with a skyscraper. Of course, they do not seem the same - time has passed between the two.

A better way to define Rock, in my opinion, is along the lines of "I know it when I see it". There are certain elements and signifiers that are common in Rock, and when a couple of them come together in a song, that song probably is Rock. In the absence of these signifiers, it probably isn't. Some of those elements are: a drum kit, an electric bass, at least one guitar, maybe an organ or later a synthesizer, a vocal line which is prominent in the song and provides a lot of the song's melodic interest, a structure of tense verses and resolved choruses, aggressive timbres and dynamics, heavy beats, extensive guitar solos which focus on technical craftsmanship, vocal techniques that range from fairly standard singing to high-pitched screaming (cf. "Child in Time", Deep Purple) or low-pitched growling (too much Death Metal to list it all), and quite often some spirit of rebellion, be it against "the establishment, or be it against prevailing trends in music. This list is definitely incomplete, and certain subgenres may value some of those points more than others.

While Rock is often associated with being harsh, and with being simple music for idiots, both of these clichés are patently untrue. Rock can be a very gentle and emotional genre (a lot of Clapton's work would come to mind), and it can be very complex at the same time (cf. Dream Theater, or the aforementioned "Child in Time", or the entirety of Pink Floyd's "The Wall").

We also have to acknowledge that the influence of Rock goes far beyond Rock itself: While Lady Gaga certainly isn't a rock musician, and wouldn't claim to be, she lists Iron Maiden's Bruce Dickinson as one of her influences as a singer. No surprise there, seeing how vastly popular and completely inescapable Rock has been for the last 70 years.

I realize that this reads as "you're asking the wrong question", but the point is, there is no neat, simple answer to this question. People love simple answers, and there have been some, but sadly, none of them really get down to the heart of the matter.

tl;dr: What is Rock? It's complicated. Don't try and put all music into neat little boxes, because music isn't made to fit into neat little boxes.

Answer (score 1):

I used to think that Avril Lavigne was rock and that Coldplay was pop, but it's actually the opposite. Avril Lavigne uses lots of guitars on her songs, sounds very close to rock'n'roll, but it's pop. And Coldplay, sound too pop for me, with much more piano/acoustic guitar than electric guitar. But it's still considered a rock band.

Wheat Williams said that rock'n'roll is defined by RHYTHM, heavy beats on 2 and 4 in a 4/4 time signature, but I'm sure I've heard this backbeat in pop music as well. If you listen to a pop song called Don't Let Me Get Me by P!nk, you'll hear that empashis on 2 and 4, with guitar, but still, it's not considered a rock song. And I've heard a rock song that doesn't follow that pattern, which the emphasis are on 1 and 3.

Comment: I have made edits to your answer to try and make it fit. You should be aware that pop music can also be rock, or jazz, or pretty much anything. And as Ulf commented, there can be exceptions to any rule.

Comment: Genre is subjective and hard to define. I consider Don't Let Me Get Me to be a rock song, along with many others of Pink's songs, and I'm far from the only one (e.g. see [this Slate podcast](https://slate.com/podcasts/hit-parade/2023/03/pink-defined-her-own-r-and-b-to-rock-genre) discussing the song and its genre). I'd say (and Slate's commentators seem to be suggesting the same thing) genre is often defined more by who the artist is rather than the content of the product, and there's a reluctance to label Pink as rock primarily because she started in R&B.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it needs to analyse not only the song, but also the artist, the context. Even Dave Grohl (Foo Fighters) compared Billie Eilish to Nirvana, stating that "rock n roll is not dead". Billie's songs are heavily influences by rap. Sometimes ppl include Elton John on rock lists.

There is not a specific rule. Electric guitar is common, but there are rock songs. Attitude is another strong characteristic of Rock songs, but Beatles started with Love Me Do, which is not rock's "attitude".

In short: does it have electric guitar + attitude? 99% chance it is rock.

Comment: Stairway to Heaven does not have "attitude", whatever that means, and for large parts is played on an acoustic guitar, or on an extremely clean electric guitar trying to imitate the acoustic sound. Is it Rock? Well, obviously it is, but under your definition, it's very easy to claim it isn't.

Comment: Uh, ok.  So, after the drums and electric guitar come in on Stairway to Heaven, it is still absent of attitude?  That's incorrect.  However, if we look to Led Zeppelin III, and listen to That's The Way, the song is completely devoid of electric guitar and drums.  This particular song is not rock, but instead whatever you classify with acoustic guitars and vocals.

Answer (score -1):

Difference between pop and rock is that rock will have a few to many off beat chord changes through out the song, very simple. Those few or more changes happen between the 1, 2, 3 and 4 downbeats. Some bands like Styx may have a couple pop ballads for radio that are pop and have no offbeat chords or punches while the majority if their catalogue is rock with offbeat chords and punched. Although as some mention, the emphasis on beat 2 and 4 are a distinction, but the offbeat chords and punches are the key

Comment: So you came to a two-year-old-question for this blatantly wrong and overly simplified answer?

Comment: *Lot's* of rock songs only have chord changes on regular beats, or even only between measures or on the 3 beat. I'd say having chord changes at offbeat locations is more likely to push a song into a subgenre, e.g. alternative rock, to be honest.

Answer (score -2):

Air Supply and Slayer are both categorized as Rock. Rock, as a term, is meaningless.

Comment: Air Supply and Slayer both perform songs in 4/4 time with the heavy beats being 2 and 4. That's why they are both rock bands.